# How to fetch record using all values in array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

values in array are dynamic can be more or less.
i am getting result if any of the value is true .
but i want to fetch record record if all values in array are true.
**Important  :** values in array are dynamic

```
 SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
                    J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
                    R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
                    J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
                    FROM df_job_meta M JOIN df_job_post J ON 
                    M.JOB_ID = J.ID JOIN df_register_users R ON 
                    R.ID = J.USER_ID WHERE J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND  M.VALUE IN ('Fresher','Full Time') group  BY J.ID
```

table:df_job_meta

```
--------------------------------------
|JOB_ID  | META_KEY    | VALUE       | 
-------------------------------------|
| 91     | experience  |Fresher      |
| 91     | work_hour   |Full Time    |
| 91     | pay_scale   |Sharing      |
| 91     | gender      |Female       |
| 92     | experience  |3 to 5 Years |
| 92     | work_hour   |Part Time    |  
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: [fetch array using mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to match the number of records returned with the number of criterias in `IN` clause. In that case, basically use

```
SELECT M.JOB_ID
FROM df_job_meta M
WHERE M.VALUE IN ('Fresher','Full Time')
GROUP BY M.JOB_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE) = 2
```

You have *2* values in array, thus count must be equal to *2*. If you have **N** values, then the query should be something like

```
SELECT M.JOB_ID
FROM df_job_meta M
WHERE M.VALUE IN (1,2,...,N)
GROUP BY M.JOB_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE) = N
```

You can implement that part with php since you have a dynamic array. And of course you need to join that query with the main query you have above.

**EDIT**

If you don't have repeating lines with the same `VALUE` for each `JOB_ID`, you can simply do `COUNT(M.VALUE)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE)`

**EDIT 2**

I've also included the full sql statement. (May have errors since ddl is not provided)

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
FROM df_job_post J JOIN df_register_users R ON R.ID = J.USER_ID 
WHERE J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' 
AND  J.ID IN 
(
    SELECT M.JOB_ID
    FROM df_job_meta M
    WHERE M.VALUE IN ('Fresher','Full Time')
    GROUP BY M.JOB_ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE) = 2
)
```

**EDIT 3**

For exact matching, you can change the query into this

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
FROM df_job_post J JOIN df_register_users R ON R.ID = J.USER_ID 
WHERE J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' 
AND  J.ID IN 
(
    SELECT M.JOB_ID
    FROM df_job_meta M
    WHERE M.VALUE IN ('Fresher','Full Time')
    GROUP BY M.JOB_ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE) = (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM df_job_meta WHERE JOB_ID = M.JOB_ID)
)
```

You're basically checking if the returned row count is equal to actual count with this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT M.VALUE) = (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM df_job_meta WHERE JOB_ID = M.JOB_ID)
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result

Comment: `df_job_meta` should have two rows with 'Fresher','Full Time' for a specific ID. are there any records that meet the criteria? also, consider the other criterias you're using in outer query.

Comment: Yes there  are more no of rows with another JOB_ID with the help of this i am fetching records from main table df_job_post

Comment: If the data you provided actually exists, then changing `2` to `4` and changing `('Fresher','Full Time')` to `('Fresher','Full Time','Female','Sharing')` should at least return `91`. If you change the subquery like that and only run the subquery, mysql should at least return 1 result which is `91`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69397/discussion-on-answer-by-ozgur-bar-how-to-fetch-record-using-all-values-in-array).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mentioned query then use this method:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
                J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
                R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
                J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
                FROM df_job_meta M JOIN df_job_post J ON 
                M.JOB_ID = J.ID JOIN df_register_users R ON 
                R.ID = J.USER_ID WHERE J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND  M.VALUE IN ('Fresher','Full Time') group  BY J.ID");

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
   echo $r['JOB_ID'].$r['META_KEY'].$r['VALUE'];
}
```

Comment: i am using pdo in this query,Above query is  after Var_dump

Comment: mysql is deprecated but the concept is not.